# Facebook Graph API - page_impressions inconsistent on set dateRange?

Tags: facebook-insights, facebook-graph-api-v2.1

I'm using Facebook Graph API v2.2 (had this problem on v2.1 as well) and I'm requesting `page_impressions` through the `insights` endpoint for a set date range: 
`01-02-2014 - 28-02-2014`.

After requesting I print out the impressions from the results, and most of the time Facebook returns a total of 6763 impressions. Sometimes though, a slightly different amount is returned but there doesn't seem to be a pattern.
I've requested the impressions 40 times. The first 11 times: 6763, then once: 6709, 5 times: 6763, 1 time: 6720 and 12 times: 6763.

Is anyone familiar with this or having the same problem?
Thanks!

EDIT: I just had a result of 248 impressions... nowhere near 6763...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this is a Facebook Bug. Found a bugreport about it on the Facebook Developers forum. Different endpoint, same problem:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/877357682326329/